# VLOOKUP substituted into sum_range for SUMIFS function

Tags: excel, range, vlookup, sumifs

[Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3HNh.jpg)I am trying to create a spreadsheet so that my team can quickly look at different metrics, which can be changed using a data validation list, over a certain period of time. In order to do this I need to use a VLOOKUP function in place of the sum_range in a SUMIFS function, but Excel does not seem to like this because it keeps giving me an formula error. I need the formula to change the column it is summing based on the selected metric.

I have been trying to use this formula with no luck

```
=SUMIFS((VLOOKUP($D$2,$R$3:$S$12,2,FALSE)),Data!$D$3:$D$1048576,$C4,Data!$Y$3:$Y$1048576,D$3,Data!$Z$3:$Z$1048576,$D$1)
```

Comment: Use `INDEX/MATCH`, not `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: VLOOKUP will only return 1 value, it will not return a range.  Some test data and expected output would really help us help you.

Comment: @BigBen I tried that and it brings up a #VALUE error where it is trying to make the sum_range the cell it finds from the index instead of the range that is displayed in the cell (i.e., $S$4 instead of Data!$N$3:$N$1048576 which is stored in the cell $S$4)

Comment: Ohhhh... use `INDIRECT`.

Comment: @BigBen That works! Yay! For anyone else needing help this was my final formula `=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(INDEX($R$4:$S$12,MATCH($D$2,$R$4:$R$12,0),2)),Data!$D$3:$D$1048576,$C4,Data!$Y$3:$Y$1048576,D$20,Data!$Z$3:$Z$1048576,$D$1)`

Comment: @BigBen Please put your indirect suggestion into an answer. That way Ashley can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Bryan - no need, since the question is already self-answered.

Comment: @BigBen I see that now. I just logged in for the first time in a while and was using the "first questions" queue thing and I couldn't see the answer, only the question and comments lol.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the INDIRECT function combined with INDEX and MATCH to get it to change to the different ranges that I wanted to look at

`=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(INDEX($R$4:$S$12,MATCH($D$2,$R$4:$R$12,0),2)),Data!$D$3:$D$1048576,$C4,Data!$Y$3:$Y$1048576,D$20,Data!$Z$3:$Z$1048576,$D$1)`